# how to order the elements of a list in Python

Tags: python

So I have a list of tuples such as this:

```
atten = [('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37), 255, 1), ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39, 56), 255, 1), ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10), 255, 1), ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7), 255, 1), ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59), 255, 1), ('903', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5), 255, 1), ('904', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7), 255, 1), ('900', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9), 255, 1), ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47), 255, 1), ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49), 255, 1), ('909', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33), 255, 1)]
```

Can someone  suggest a way to do this ? I'd like to get this result :

```
14 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47), 255, 1)]

901 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39, 56),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59),datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49)]

903 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5), 255, 1)]

904 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7)]

900 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9)]

909 = [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33)]
```

Comment: You can't assign integers as variable names. BTW What have you tried so far?

Comment: You are going to want a dictionary because, as stated, you can't have just numerical values as names, nor would you want to create all the names in the global namespace

Comment: They already did. The expected output clearly shows multiple timestamps against the `14` key

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a dict comprehension using `itertools.groupby` and `operator.itemgetter`:

```
#sort the list first
atten.sort()
grouped = {k: [e[1] for e in g] for k, g in groupby(atten, itemgetter(0))}
```

Results:

```
{'14': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47)],
 '900': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9)],
 '901': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39,56), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49)],
 '903': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5)],
 '904': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7)],
 '909': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33)]}
```

Comment: No it can't. You've lost the duplicates against the `14` and `901` keys that are clearly visible in the input data and the expected output

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `defaultdict` with `list` as the standard parameter

```
import datetime

atten = [('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37), 255, 1),
         ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39, 56), 255, 1),
         ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10), 255, 1),
         ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7), 255, 1),
         ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59), 255, 1),
         ('903', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5), 255, 1),
         ('904', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7), 255, 1),
         ('900', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9), 255, 1),
         ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47), 255, 1),
         ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49), 255, 1),
         ('909', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33), 255, 1)]

from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for item in atten:
    result[item[0]].append(item[1])

print(result)
```

Which yields

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'903': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5)], '900': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9)], '901': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39, 56), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49)], '14': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47)], '904': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7)], '909': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33)]})
```

Comment: That's exploiting side effects. Why you would want `_ = [result[item[0]].append(item[1]) for item in atten]` to just eat up a non(e)-sensical list rather than just use a loop is beyond me. That's bad practice

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers are just getting more and more elaborate. You just need (or, really, want) a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
atten = [('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37), 255, 1), 
         ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39, 56), 255, 1), 
         ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10), 255, 1), 
         ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7), 255, 1), 
         ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59), 255, 1), 
         ('903', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5), 255, 1), 
         ('904', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7), 255, 1), 
         ('900', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9), 255, 1), 
         ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47), 255, 1), 
         ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49), 255, 1), 
         ('909', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33), 255, 1)]

aggregated = defaultdict(list)
for row in atten:
    aggregated[row[0]].append(row[1])
```

That's it. There's no need for `map`, `lambda`, dict comprehensions or anything. They will be slower and are harder to mentally grok. 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a `dict` to group the elements using the first tuple value as the key, and append the rest of the tuple to the value (setting the default to an empty list).

```py
import datetime

array = [('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37), 255, 1), ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39, 56), 255, 1), ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10), 255, 1), ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7), 255, 1), ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59), 255, 1), ('903', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5), 255, 1), ('904', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7), 255, 1), ('900', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9), 255, 1), ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47), 255, 1), ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49), 255, 1), ('909', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33), 255, 1)]

def group(array): 
    res = {}
    for elem in array:
        key = elem[0]
        rest = elem[1:]
        res.setdefault(key, []).append(rest)
    return res

grouped_array = group(array)
print(grouped_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

To group dates based on the initial value of each `tuple` you would use a `for` and default value in a `dictionary`:

```
import datetime


atten = [
    ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37), 255, 1),
    ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39, 56), 255, 1),
    ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10), 255, 1),
    ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7), 255, 1),
    ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59), 255, 1),
    ('903', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5), 255, 1),
    ('904', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7), 255, 1),
    ('900', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9), 255, 1),
    ('14', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47), 255, 1),
    ('901', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49), 255, 1),
    ('909', datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33), 255, 1)
]

grouped_data = {}
for data in atten:
    index = data[0]
    date = data[1]

    grouped_data[index] = grouped_data.get(index, []) + [date]

print(grouped_data)

#{
#    '14': [
#                datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 37), 
#                datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 7), 
#                datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 47)
#     ], 
#     '901': [
#                datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 39, 56),
#                datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 49, 10), 
#                datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 50, 59),
#                datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 49)
#     ], 
#     '903': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 5)], 
#     '904': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 7)], 
#     '900': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 51, 9)], 
#     '909': [datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 20, 16, 52, 33)]
#}
```